# Eclipse projects are not visible in workspace folder

Tags: eclipse, window, windows-10, eclipse-neon

The weird part is I can see my projects through package explorer.
I can also export them.
But when I want to access them elsewhere e.g windows explorer, they are not there.
All I see is .metadata folder.

An unexpected shutdown of the system occurred not too long ago.

Edit: When I switched the workspace, created and opened a project, they're still not visible/accessible outside of the eclipse project explorer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely haven't ticked "Copy projects into workspace" checkbox option.

> File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace:

[image: Copy projects into workspace]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the projects were not put into the default, workspace folder.

To check this, right click on such a project, select `Properties` (it is usually available at the bottom of the list), go to the `Resources` tab, where you have the location of the project files displayed.

[image: Project location in a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is a problem with Windows explorer and OneDrive in particular.

When I navigate to `C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/workspace` or through command line I do see my eclipse projects.
But when I try to use 'Open file..' option from any application or navigate through Windows explorer, projects are not recognized nor displayed.